# I can not send large files

Tags: php, html

I try to upload a file using PHP, when the file is not big enough everything goes well, but when the file reaches a little 15Mo I have an error message that appears ! Here is some of the code used for the upload

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group">
          <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
             <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> Attachment
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
     </div>
```

This is where I have the problem:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Comment: increase file upload limit in `php.ini` file

Comment: the limit is due to limit configured on your web-server.. what are you using for your web server ? nginx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increase your file upload as well as post limit.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 50M
```

You can use [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) method as below.

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '50M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');
```

[More Deatils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem

Comment: Yes, I have to wait 4 minute ^^